# ios - i make messenger app APNS based, but if client's notification set off , client doesn't receive message by the other client sent by APNS

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, message

My app gives and takes message by APNS. 
but if client's notification set off ,  client doesn't receive message by the other client sent by APNS.

Is this wrong way?
If it is not, how does client receive message When client's notification sets off?

Answer (score 2):

You can't rely on APNs alone for this. Notifications can be turned off and even if they are on, APNs is a "best-effort delivery" service. This means it makes no guarantee that the client will ever receive the notification, but it tries its best to deliver it. Your app should query the server for new messages, and notifications can help you make the query at the right moment. Your server can notify your app that there's a new message, then the app calls the server to get that message. But of course since notifications aren't guaranteed, your app has to reach out to the server at other times also i.e. when it enters foreground.